# How do I prevent html element from being pushed down when dragging an element over?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, drag-and-drop

I'm writing an angular directive using HTML Drag & Drop API. The directive works fine however it adds up an empty space between the elements when dragging an element over the other.

For instance:
[PFA Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOg8l.png)

[image]

I have 4 div blocks(please refer to the attachment), when I try dragging element #3 over #1, element #3 is getting pushed toward the right side and an empty space is getting added in place of element #3.

Below is my code:

**widgets.html**

```
`<div class="row" widgets-options="dm.options" ng-model="dm.blocks">
      <div class="col-md-6 columns handle" ng-repeat="block in dm.blocks">
        <div class="well">
          <span>{{block.title}}</span>
          <span>{{block.desc}}</span> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`
```

**widgets.css**

```
[draggable] {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  /* Required to make elements draggable in old WebKit */
  -khtml-user-drag: element;
  -webkit-user-drag: element;
}

.droppable.over,
.widgets-options .over {
  border: 2px dashed #999;
}

.widgets-options.handle {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.droppable.moving,
.widgets-options .moving {
  border: 2px solid #777;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
  -o-transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

Could you please let me know where am I going wrong? any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out.  `border: 2px dashed #999;` was causing the issue in my case, it was pushing other elements down. I fixed it by adding a transparent border to all the elements.

```
.droppable.over,
.widgets-options.handle.over {
  border: 2px dashed #999;
}

.widgets-options.handle {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```